# Правильно ли употребляется слово "центр"?

Tags: грамотная-речь

В последние годы у слова "центр" появилось новое значение - некая организация. Есть центры консультационные, учебные, образовательные, адвокатские, экспертные - в общем, разные. И не всегда это центры соотносятся с основным значением слова - важный, основной пункт чего-либо...
В связи с этим вопрос: грамотно ли следующее сочетание - консультационный центр русского языка (на самом деле там ведется преподавание русского языка индивидуально и в группах для детей и взрослых).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Мне кажется, тут надо знать, что представляет собой данная организация. Если она явлется головной, самой крупной или важной в группе других аналогичных организаций такого же толка, то вполне. Если же это просто обычная контора, то "центр" для нее слишком громкое название.
Впрочем, сейчас модно называть "супермаркетами" мелкие лавочки, "центрами" - второстепенные конторы и т.д.

Comment: Мелкая контора. но единственная. И само сочетание - центр русского языка?

Answer (score 2):

Мне "центр русского языка" тоже не нравится. А вот название магазина "Центр вкуса" меня почему-то не коробило. И чем это, интересно, торговля лучше русского языка? ))) Имхо, это новое явление  - называть "центром" даже самую незначительную структуру дабы придать ей весомость - в языке скорее всего приживётся и перестанет резать слух.